# Treat ListBox as MultiSelector

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, multi-select

For some reason a [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a [MultiSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead it implements its own SelectedItems property.
I have a [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) and a ListBox and I want to treat them both as a MultiSelector, so that I can do something like this:

```
var selectedItems = dataGridOrListBox.SelectedItems;
```

Is there a way to do this?
Also is there a good reason for ListBox not being a MultiSelector?

Comment: "is there a good reason for ListBox not being a MultiSelector". Yes, MultiSelector is there since framework version 3.5, while ListBox is older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own MultiSelector interface and derived ListBox and DataGrid classes that implement it:

```
public interface IMultiSelector
{
    IList SelectedItems { get; }
}

public class MyListBox : ListBox, IMultiSelector
{
}

public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid, IMultiSelector
{
}
```

Use them in XAML like this:

```
<local:MyListBox ... SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"/>
<local:MyDataGrid ... SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"/>
```

Now you could access the common SelectedItems property (e.g. in a common SelectionChanged handler) like this:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var multiSelector = (IMultiSelector)sender;
    var selectedItems = multiSelector.SelectedItems;
    ...
}
```